# How to give root permission for permanent to an existing user?

Tags: permissions, root

There are two user like "root" and a "normal" user In my Ubuntu . Now I want to give permanent root permission to the "normal" user without losing any data . I actually work with "normal" user for a long time . And now I want to move "normal" user to "root" user.

But the problem is that when I  log in with "root" user then all the previous data such as application+browser cache + etc are missing .That's why I want to give permanent root permission to the "normal" user . How can I do that?

Comment: Working as `root` is really discouraged and some GUI programs will even refuse to start for security reasons. One mistyped command could wipe your system. You can use `su`, `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` to get a root shell for doing administration tasks, but you really shouldn't login to a GUI session as root user.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to make a user an administrator on an Ubuntu system is to add them to the `sudo` group so they can use `sudo` to execute things as root when needed.

```
# usermod -a -G sudo normal
```

That adds the user `normal` to the `sudo` group. After that user logs in again they should be able to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

add string `username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` to file `/etc/sudoers` where `username` is login of "normal" user or add user to "sudo" group as mentioned above